# categorize contacts based on their mobile operator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a windows phone app that searches the contacts, then categorize them based on their mobile operator, so it basically searches for the first 3 digits of a phone number to tell which operator it belongs to, then adds it to a list, any guidance how to do that, as I'm totally noob and learning through trial and error, Thanks.

Comment: In Germany it's possible to transfer the phone number to another operator, so the number does not necessarily indicate the mobile operator. Maybe in your case, you have to consider this, too.

Comment: Not only in Germany. Adam - keep that in mind.

Comment: there is still some countries that you can tell the mobile operator just by looking at the phone number prefix, i'm in africa right now, and this is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read existing contact data using Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts class. Here is a sample code:

```
private void ButtonContacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Contacts cons = new Contacts();

    //Add an event handler for SearchCompleted event
    cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

    //Read existing contacts, FilterKind.None will return all contacts
    cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
}

void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs args)
{
    //Do something with the results
    //Following code simply prints the phone numbers
    foreach (Contact contact in args.Results)
       foreach (ContactPhoneNumber phoneno in contact.PhoneNumbers)
          Debug.WriteLine(phoneno.PhoneNumber);    
}
```

You'll need the add capability declaration for ID_CAP_CONTACTS in WMAppManifest.xml.